# Audio missing after rendering video

Tags: rendering, audio

Every time I render my video's, the audio goes missing. I don't hear any audio during editing or post render. I've put **Audio Codec** to 'ACC' or 'MP3', so I don't understand why this is an issue.
Thanks.

Comment: if you don't hear audio during editing you won't hear it after render either. could your audio strips be hidden? (alt-H to unhide)

Comment: I pressed alt-H, although I'm not sure what I'm meant to be looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I'm under 'compositing' to remove green screen. This may be the reason why I can't hear audio?

Comment: oh okay, well I only know how to add audio to the video sequencer (VSE). Not sure how to, or even if you can, add audio to the compositor tbh

Comment: Okay, I'll keep looking - thanks a lot for your help:D

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. The solution comes from Richard Antalik,developer.blender org
'Enable Sequencer in Output Properties > Post Processing panel.'

In case you are not familiar with things. (in Blender 3.0 at least) The Output Properties (tab) is where you define the size of your output, where to output your file to, encoding for video and audio, etc. You will also find in the same tab the Post Processing panel with compositing and sequencer check boxes. Put a *Check on the sequencer*
Good luck.